# Custom Button touchUpInside event not fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uibutton

My custom button touchupinside event not fire when I put some code in my custom button

**Note: When I tap on button this method is fire but touchUpInside method not fire**

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchBegan");
    [Singleton playSoundForEvent:Sound_ButtonTap];
}
```

If I remove above code then working fine.

Above code reason : I don't put tap sound everywhere on touchupinside.
I would like only One line code in whole project.

Comment: touchesBegan called for every UIcontrols then how will you handle this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please check below answer, It will woking fine for me, so my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the call to `super`

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

The reason it doesn't work without the call to super, is that a button needs to register touch events (`touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesCanceled`) to be able to map them to `UIControlEvent`, and only then fire actions with `sendAction`.

Full code

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touchBegan");
    [Singleton playSoundForEvent:Sound_ButtonTap];
}
```

Comment: Yes, because then your custom button uses its parent function.

Comment: Where I put code `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];`

Comment: At the beginning of your function

Comment: As you say every send event put into this method ? like `Value Change`, `TouchUpInside` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code and test again I hope It will working fine.

`[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];`